# listchars causing E474: Invalid argument in recent versions of vim

Tags: vim

The snippet below has been in my vimrc for quite some time, recently (in the latest versions of vim) I am getting an error in the forth line:

```
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,trail:◇,extends:»,precedes:«,eol:¬ " show tabs et. al.
```

I have not made any changes to my vimrc file and yet now I am getting this error:

```
Error detected while processing $HOME/.vim/rcfiles/editing:
line   11:
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:�~V�\ ,trail:�~W~G,extends:»,precedes:«,eol:¬
```

line 11 is the 4th line in the snippet.

```
set list                                            " show invisibles
set listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:-,extends:>,precedes:<,eol:$ " show tabs et. al.
if v:version >= 703
  set listchars=tab:▸\ ,trail:◇,extends:»,precedes:«,eol:¬ " show tabs et. al.
  if (&termencoding ==# 'utf-8' || &encoding ==# 'utf-8')
    let &listchars="tab:\u21e5 ,trail:\u2423,extends:\u21c9,precedes:\u21c7,nbsp:\u00b7,eol:\u00ac"
    let &listchars="tab:\u25b8 ,trail:\u25c7,extends:\u00bb,precedes:\u00ab,nbsp:\u00b7,eol:\u00ac"
  endif
```

I haven't yet tried to go back to older versions where it works but I know that the error is thrown in version 8.0.1453 on one machine and version 8.2.2100 on another.

Oddly, if I type (or copy and paste) this line into vim, it is accepted with no problem, but in my vimrc I get an error on startup.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found that adding "set encoding=utf-8 nobomb" before this snippet stops the error